# Http Request sent multiple times in Angular 6 app

Tags: angular, httprequest, rxjs6, angular-http-interceptors

In our angular 6 application, I noticed some Http GET calls are executed at least two times. Sometimes the OPTIONS and/or the first GET is cancelled and only the second call succeeds. In other cases the same GET call is executed two or more times.

[image]

A footer component calls a service to get the current application version and display it its template. A simple Observable with subscription, without any special operator.

**UPDATE**
After further investigation, the issue seems to be with the `combineLatest` in the HttpInterceptor. As the two observables are emitted as observables by a BehaviourSubject (each), I guess the different speed/time when those Subjects emit, make it so that the combineLates is triggered twice or more.

**Impersonator service** (emits observables from a BehaviourSubject)

```
export class ImpersonatorService {
public get changeHandler(): Observable<string> {
    return this.changeHandlerInternal.asObservable();
}

private changeHandlerInternal = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.get());
private key = "impersonate";
constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}

public set(impersonate: string) {
    this.cookieService.put(this.key, impersonate);
    this.changeHandlerInternal.next(impersonate);
}

private get(): string {
    let impersonate = this.cookieService.get(this.key);
    if (impersonate === undefined || impersonate === null || impersonate === "") {
        impersonate = "";
    }

    return impersonate;
}
}
```

**Footer component**:

```
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {
public applicationInfo: Observable<ApplicationInfo>;

constructor(private applicationService: ApplicationInfoService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.applicationInfo = applicationService.getApplicationInfo();
  }
}
```

**Footer Template**

```
<div>
    {{ (applicationInfo | async)?.version }}
</div>
```

**Application Service**

```
export class ApplicationInfoService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: IAppConfig) {}

public getApplicationInfo(): Observable<ApplicationInfo> {
    return this.http.get<ApplicationInfo>(this.config.apiEndpoint + "/api/applicationinfo");
   }
}
```

The application service is called only from the footer component.

We also use an HttpInterceptor to inject headers:

```
export class HttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private impersonator: ImpersonatorService, private profileService: ProfileService, private languageService: TranslateService) {}

public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.impersonator.changeHandler
        .combineLatest(this.profileService.changeHandler, (user, profile) => {
            let customHeaders = req.headers.set("X-Impersonate", user).set("X-Profile", profile);

            if (customHeaders.has("Content-Type")) {
                if (customHeaders.get("Content-Type") === "multipart/form-data") {
                    customHeaders = customHeaders.delete("Content-Type");
                }
            } else {
                customHeaders = customHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
            }

            const clonedReq = req.clone({ headers: customHeaders, withCredentials: true });
            return next.handle(clonedReq);
        })
        .switch();
    }
}
```

Reading from other SO responses, it seems related to a race issue. However the other cases found were using switchMap or other operators causing issues in those scenarios.

By debugging, I can see that inside the HttpInterceptor two requests for ApplicationInfo endpoint arrive. But how can I ensure that no duplicates requests are shipped?

Comment: Are you using Angular Universal?

Comment: No, just angular 6 CLI.

Comment: @Francesco, did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Yes, I found out that there was a mistake with Subject ans Observables in our HTTP Interceptor class. From two different sources we were emitting an initial value on a Form Setup that was triggering an HTTP GET and then we were executing another GET to retrieve the data. I solved the issue by preventing the Subject from emitting on initial value from the form.